# How to select or query date from date column using PHP MSQL using Jquery date time picker?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I want to select or query date using jquery date picker. I have date column field as you can see screenshot below.If i choose the date which i need to generate and show the result in a given date.for example, i select date 10-12-2012 and show all the data which inputed in that date.Please help me!

Comment: You need to tell a little more detail in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong, but it seems you're trying to perform a query statement when a date from date-picker is selected.
For that, you should use jquery.post or .get feature.

First you need to create a php file who performs the query statement with a $_GET or $_POST 
message with the date to search.

something like

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['pickdate'])){
 //set a variable $datepicked
 //Prepare your SQL statement "Select * from table where date='$datepicked'"
//run the query 
//echo the result with divs and style stuff
} ?>
```

Then in your jquery function you just call the php file through a .get function triggered with your event

```
$.get('phppickdate.php', {pickdate:datepicked },function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

Create a div in same html/php document

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

I can't remember quite good the code but it's something like that.